# Polymorphism with Code First and DBContext

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

We have a project where we have multiple solutions that all share a common core library. Our core library has all of our default entities, data context, and utilities that work with this context. I'd like to have the web project extend the core context, but I seem to always get either no migration or multiple database. Essentially, I want to be able to have

```
namespace Core
{
    public class BaseContext : DbContext
    {
        DBSet<SomeCoreEntity> CoreEntities {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Then have

```
namespace Web
{
    public class DerivedContext : Core.BaseContext
    {
        DBSet<SomeNewEntity> NewEntities {get;set;}
    }
}
```

From here, I want in the core to be able to have

```
baseContextInstance.CoreEntities
```

and

```
derivedContextInstance.CoreEntites
```

to refer to the same table, but the derived context would also have access to NewEntites. What is the right way to do this? Does it require something special in the web.config, maybe with DatabaseInitializerForType? I've looked around and can't find any good documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried using Partial classes? Set the Core class to `public partial class`, and the same in the website. You may need to change the website namespace around that class to `Core` rather than web too.

Also, I suspect you will need to do the DB migration from inside the website, not inside the core library. Otherwise the core can only see the classes inside itself.

Comment: You can't have a partial class across assemblies. Once we build our core library the meta data is written and the class is no longer partial.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I thought you could, but clearly I've never actually attempted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like it's possible, if you ensure that the Derived and base contexts essentially use the same ConnectionString keys. You could have them use different keys, but it would only cause duplication that you would need to maintain.

**NB:** I am using `update-database` and `Enable-Migrations` commands from the package manager. The general philosophy for other deployment processes *should* be the same, but I haven't tested it.

First, create your base context (and the associated DbSet classes):

```
namespace Core
{
    public partial class BaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public BaseContext()
        {

        }

        public BaseContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<SystemUser> SystemUser { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SystemUser
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next, create your Derived Context (with the new classes):

```
namespace Web
{
    public class DerivedContext : Core.BaseContext
    {
        public DerivedContext()
            : base("BaseContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So far, this is pretty much what you've done However, note two things:

1. `BaseContext` exposes a constructor that takes the connectionstring (or connection string key name) - this passes into the same constructor in `DbContext`
2. The Derived Context passes the key name "BaseContext" down to `BaseContext`

Now, add a connectionstring entry to your `.config` file in the Web project, with the key name `BaseContext`, and the appropriate connectionstring.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BaseContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Add a migration to the Web Project by entering the below to the Package Manager console (ensure you have the web project selected from the dropdown):

```
Enable-Migrations
```

Enter the Migration file created, and change AutomaticMigrations to true in the constructor

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
}
```

Now, when you publish from the Web Project, using the following in the PM console:

```
Update-Database
```

It will publish both `SystemUser` and `Order` to a new DB (called `TestDb` in my example).

---

**Usage:**

If you examine your DB, you will note that it has successfully created both the SystemUsers and Orders tables.

If you run the below code from your application:

```
using (var ctxt = new Core.BaseContext())
{
    var user1 = new Core.SystemUser()
    {
        Forename = "Obsidian",
        Surname = "Phoenix"
    };

    ctxt.SystemUser.Add(user1);

    ctxt.SaveChanges();
}

using (var ctxt = new DerivedContext())
{
    var user2 = new Core.SystemUser()
    {
        Forename = "John",
        Surname = "Doe"
    };

    ctxt.SystemUser.Add(user2);

    ctxt.SaveChanges();


    var users = ctxt.SystemUser.ToList();

    users.ForEach(u => Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", u.Forename, u.Surname)));

    var order = new Order()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Item = "Test Item",
        Quantity = 1
    };

    ctxt.Orders.Add(order);

    ctxt.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can see that I can use both the `BaseContext` *and* the `DerivedContext` to read/write to `Systemuser`, and I can use the `DerivedContext` to read/write to `Order`.

Comment: This 95% got me where I need to be. The only issue seems to be data seeding. The initializer for whichever context is referenced first is what will run, so I've had to add a quick call to fetch some object from the derived context in Application_Start to make sure the data loads. A little hacky, but it seems to work well enough.

Comment: Actually, it seems I can just call derivedContext.Database.Initialize(false); which smells a lot less to me.

Comment: Yeah, that does sound a lot less hacky. Glad it helped.